# How to align in memory the array payload of a ByteArray# with GHC Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, primitive, memory-alignment

I have a few questions about how to align not a `ByteArray#` but a `ByteArray#`'s *array payload* (the actual bytes of nonmetadata data stored in the array), which might be complicated by the fact that the RTS stores array metadata in the memory *right before* the array payload:

> [If you have a value of type `ByteArray#`, it definitely points to a heap object with type `ARR_WORDS` (see below)…](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects)
>
> [⋮](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects)
>
> [`ARR_WORDS`, `MUT_ARR_PTRS_CLEAN`, `MUT_ARR_PTRS_DIRTY`, `MUT_ARR_PTRS_FROZEN0`, `MUT_ARR_PTRS_FROZEN`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects)
>
> [Non-pointer arrays are straightforward:](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects)
>
> [`| Header | Bytes | Array payload |`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects)

- Does `newAlignedPinnedByteArray#` already work around this by specifically aligning the array payload rather than aligning everything including the metadata?
- Assuming that it doesn't, the number of bytes the metadata takes up can presumably change with new GHC versions. How can I determine how many bytes that takes up at my module's compiletime (I'm perfectly happy to use Template Haskell or some sort of Cabal trickery)?
- How can I use that information to figure out how much larger I should make the array to accomodate padding to get alignment of the array payload?
- How can I use that information to get an `Addr#` to the padded start of the array payload?

Please ensure that your suggestions for getting the proper alignment cannot be undone even if the copying garbage collector doesn't care about alignment.

Comment: Some other misc info here: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14731

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the GHC source code in `PrimOps.cmm` where the alignment is performed:

```
/* Now we need to move p forward so that the payload is aligned
   to <alignment> bytes. Note that we are assuming that
   <alignment> is a power of 2, which is technically not guaranteed */
p = p + ((-p - SIZEOF_StgArrBytes) & (alignment - 1));
```

So, it is the **payload** that is aligned, not the header.